# How can I make the "top" position of an element equal to that of another + 60px?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following div element `FirstDiv` with inline style settings:

```
<div  class="FirstDiv" style="position:absolute;top:16%;height:50%; width:24%;</div>
```

When a button is pressed, I'm using `toggleClass` to add `SecondDiv`to `FirstDiv` so that the top shifts down by 20px. Here's the (unsuccessful) JQuery that I've attempted using a combination of CSS & JQuery. (I'm not even sure if you can merge CSS / Jquery this way.)

```
<style type="text/javascript">
    .`SecondDiv`{
    top:($(".FirstDiv").position().top + '20px') !important;
    }
</style>
```

I have also tried `.offset().` in place of `.position()` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript, not CSS.

Comment: @ThomasLandauer Take a look at the structure of it. It's set in `css`. I'll add further details to help you out.

Comment: I added an other method to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use jQuery inside a stylesheet, that's not quite how it works. You'll need to write a javascript script to modify the html elements to make it move. Jquery will select your element:

```
$(".special")
```

Then you can toggle a class with it using `toggleClass("move")`. This will add the class if it's missing, or remove it if it's there.

You can the effect you want by toggling a class that redefines the `top` property of your element. It's possible to add or subtract `20px` to/from it by using `calc(...)`.

See:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#moveButton").click(function(){
    $(".special").toggleClass("move");
  });
});
```

```css
.special{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 3px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20px;
}

.move{
  top: calc(20% + 20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="special">
    I am special!
</div>
<button id="moveButton" type="button">Move Special</button>
```

Comment: `top: calc(20% - 20px);` is exactly what I needed! My first attempt was `20% - 20px` without the `Calc()` Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

how about giving the SecondDivs a negative top margin?

```
<div  class="FirstDiv" style="position:absolute;top:16%;height:50%; width:24%;"></div>
<div  class="SecondDiv" style="position:absolute;top:16%;height:50%; width:24%; margin-top: -20px;"></div>
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I need to base the top position (or margin-top) on that of the first Div. Specifically, I'm using toggleClass to add the class `SecondDiv` to `FirstDiv` when a button is clicked. So there aren't actually 2 separate divs (I just explained it as such to try to make the problem more straightforward.) I'll clarify in the OP

Comment: @Snoops: That should still work fine if you style `.SecondDiv { margin-top: -20px; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I've only been doing this for a few years but I've never seen jQuery that looks like what you've shared :/ Specifically `."SecondDiv"{}` as well as the `!important` as part of the jQuery. Seems like you're merging CSS and jQuery in an unholy way.

That's not to say you're not on the right track:

```
var newTop = $('.FirstDiv').offset().top + 20;
$('.SecondDiv').css({ top: newTop + 'px' });
```

You can also set margin this way:

```
 $('.SecondDiv').css({ 'margin-top' : newTop + 'px' });
```

[Here is a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkaus1x3/1/), hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this won't toggle. I'm trying to  toggle this setting so that if a button is pressed and the top-margin is 16%, it will add 20px to that. If the button is pressed again, those extra 20px disappear. That's why I figured I'd try using `toggleClass` and define the top of the second class based on that of the first.

Comment: Check out the jsFiddle I've updated. I added some toggle functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this! This solution definitely works, but @Don answered my question a bit sooner and I think his solution is a bit more straightforward so I accepted his answer. Thanks again, though!

Comment: No problem, as long as you got the help you were after!

Answer (score -1):

In both example click blue div.

Toggling class with jQuery, but in this case you have not to specific "16%" in both classes (FirstDiv and SecondDiv). In this case we don't use "calc". In this case we have possibility to use every "top", passing parameter to "changeTop" function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .FirstDiv {
            position: absolute;
            height: 50%;
            width: 24%;
            background: blue;
            top: 16%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var changeTop = function (topIncrement) {
            if (!$('.FirstDiv').data('originalTop')) {
                var top = $('.FirstDiv').position().top;
                $('.FirstDiv').data('originalTop', top)
            }
            var originalTop = parseFloat($('.FirstDiv').data('originalTop'));
            var newTop;
            if ($('.FirstDiv').hasClass('SecondDiv')) {
                newTop = originalTop;
            }
            else {
                newTop = originalTop + parseFloat(topIncrement);
            }

            $('.FirstDiv').toggleClass('SecondDiv').css('top', newTop);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="FirstDiv" onclick="changeTop(20)"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is Don's case. Toggling class with jQuery. In this case you have to specific "16%" in both classes (FirstDiv and SecondDiv).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.FirstDiv {
 position: absolute;
 height: 50%;
 width: 24%;
 background: blue;
 top: 16%;
}

.SecondDiv {
 top: calc(16% + 20px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="FirstDiv" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('SecondDiv')"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: with css pre-processors like Sass and Less you can get rid of the duplicated constants with variables... or hell I'm pretty sure css variables will handle this now, though I believe they aren't supported by older browsers